# send all contact to other

Tags: query-string, contacts, telegram

I want to send many or all my telegram contacts by query string to some one else, how can I do ?

this is a code for sending one contact:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/sendContact?chat_id=....&phone_number=......&first_name=.....
```

but is there a way to send all or too many contacts in one request?

Thanks

Comment: The query string is very limited and browser dependent see details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/3029422)

Comment: a better way is to export the contacts using the [contacts.getContacts](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getContacts) method

Comment: what about Php, are Php codes could do that?

Comment: what is your use case? could you please describe what are you trying to do?

Comment: When you share contact by a bot to others, telegram send back the User Id, so you can collect many phone numbers and it's related id, with this two property you could find phone number of any unknown user.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but **it isn't possible.**

Please read [Telegram Bots API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Comment: It is Possible, just need and infinite number of automated request to server.

Comment: @Salmaan yes, but you must manually specify your contacts in code and prepare x requests.

Comment: yes, but it's easy to specify contacts, the problem is sending many requests that result in failure